# HttpClient HttpPost results in HTTP 400 response

Tags: java, http, soap, http-post

I am writing a SOAP client using `org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient` to make a SOAP call to an external system via a proxy server.

From the log file it looks like the connection through the proxy server succeeded but the POST request to the external system endpoint is resulting in **HTTP 400 Bad Request** response.

I am unable to figure out what is causing this error. Can anyone take a look and see what am missing? Thanks for your help in advance.

```
[4/20/15 20:37:04:850 EDT] 0000001c wire          1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire wire http-outgoing-2 >> "POST /Staging/DataTransfer.asmx HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[4/20/15 20:37:04:850 EDT] 0000001c wire          1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire wire http-outgoing-2 >> "SOAPAction: http://data.types.services.ecomm.stores.com/TransferCart[\r][\n]"
[4/20/15 20:37:04:850 EDT] 0000001c wire          1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire wire http-outgoing-2 >> "Content-Type: text/xml[\r][\n]"
[4/20/15 20:37:04:865 EDT] 0000001c wire          1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire wire http-outgoing-2 >> "Accept-Encoding: text/xml[\r][\n]"
[4/20/15 20:37:04:865 EDT] 0000001c wire          1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire wire http-outgoing-2 >> "Content-Length: 2022[\r][\n]"
[4/20/15 20:37:04:865 EDT] 0000001c wire          1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire wire http-outgoing-2 >> "Host: abc.test.com:443[\r][\n]"
[4/20/15 20:37:04:865 EDT] 0000001c wire          1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire wire http-outgoing-2 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[4/20/15 20:37:04:865 EDT] 0000001c wire          1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire wire http-outgoing-2 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java/1.6.0)[\r][\n]"
[4/20/15 20:37:04:865 EDT] 0000001c wire          1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire wire http-outgoing-2 >> "[\r][\n]"
[4/20/15 20:37:04:865 EDT] 0000001c wire          1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire wire http-outgoing-2 >> "TESTDATA"
[4/20/15 20:37:05:099 EDT] 0000001c wire          1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire wire http-outgoing-2 << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]"
[4/20/15 20:37:05:099 EDT] 0000001c wire          1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire wire http-outgoing-2 << "via: IG Proxy[\r][\n]"
[4/20/15 20:37:05:099 EDT] 0000001c wire          1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire wire http-outgoing-2 << "Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2015 00:37:01 GMT[\r][\n]"
[4/20/15 20:37:05:099 EDT] 0000001c wire          1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire wire http-outgoing-2 << "Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0[\r][\n]"
[4/20/15 20:37:05:099 EDT] 0000001c wire          1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire wire http-outgoing-2 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[4/20/15 20:37:05:099 EDT] 0000001c wire          1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire wire http-outgoing-2 << "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii[\r][\n]"
[4/20/15 20:37:05:099 EDT] 0000001c wire          1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire wire http-outgoing-2 << "Content-Length: 311[\r][\n]"
[4/20/15 20:37:05:099 EDT] 0000001c wire          1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire wire http-outgoing-2 << "[\r][\n]"
```

Sure - here is the code:

```
            CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASSWORD));
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();

        HttpHost target = new HttpHost(ENDPOINT_HOST, 443, "https");
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT);

        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setProxy(proxy)
        .build();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(ENDPOINT_API_URL);
        httppost.setConfig(config);
        httppost.setHeader("SOAPAction", SOAPAction);
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;");
        httppost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "text/xml"); 
        httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(postBody, "UTF-8"));

        //if(LOG.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) 
        LOG.info("Executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine() + " to " + target + " via " + proxy);

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, httppost);

        LOG.info("CartTransfer HTTP Status=" + response.getStatusLine());
```

Comment: Please provide us with the means to assist you. TL;DR post your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be just about anything above/beyond your TCP/IP-level "connect".  Look here for a few examples:

- https://codinglifestyle.wordpress.com/2012/12/05/soapextensions-a-bad-day-with-http-400-bad-requests/

STRONG SUGGESTIONS:

- Get [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/downloads/latest-release.html), if you don't already have it.  Create a dummy SOAP response, point your client at SoapUI, and verify the request is OK (it sounds like it is).  Then create a dummy SOAP request, and point SoapUI at your server.  See if you can determine exactly "what's going wrong".
- Get [Fiddler2](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler2), if you don't already have it.  Observe the traffic back and forth (requests and responses).
- Turn on full logging on the server to better understand "what's going wrong".

Q: What language and SOAP library are you using on the client?  On the server?

Q: Would it be possible to post example snippets of the failing client-side code and server-side code?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for looking into it and taking the time to respond.

The problem was simpler than i expected. The service expects two strings. One of the strings I send is in XML format and this was confusing the service. Once I encoded the string, the server was able to receive and parse the request.